# least cost or lowest cost?

Tags: expressions

In a novel routing algorithm, a router has several available interfaces to forward a packet.  Will it choose the interface with the "least cost" or "lowest cost" to forward the packet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why this got downvoted, with no answers or comments.

This is kind of a tough one. I'm not sure what the actual grammatical rules (i.e. what's correct and what isn't) regarding this. I do know that both terms are quite common. Terms that describe mathematics always use "least" (such as "least common denominator"). I believe that "least" is the most proper, but if you said "lowest" in colloquial conversation I don't think anyone would care.